# Скажите как сохранить координаты после использования getCurrentPosition?

Tags: reactjs, redux, геолокация

Всем привет.

Ситуация следующая: работаю в реакте, в методе `componentDidMount` необходимо получить текущие координаты и передать их через редакс в `action`. Не удаётся сохранить координаты, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?
От отчаяния уже пытался в переменные сохранить - безрезультатно.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let lat;
  let lon;

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    const {
      coords: { latitude, longitude }
    } = position;
    lat = latitude;
    lon = longitude;
  });

  console.log('coords after getCurrentPosition', lat, lon) // выводит undefined

  this.props.weatherInfo(lat, lon);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Метод [`Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) используется для
>   получения текущего местоположения устройства. В качестве первого
>   параметра метод принимает функцию обратного вызова (коллбэк), которая
>   принимает объект `Position` в качестве единственного входного
>   параметра.

Это означает, что код коллбэка будет выполнен не сразу, а спустя некоторое время - поэтому Вы получаете `undefined` в результате. Чтобы сохранить текущее местоположение - необходимо делать это внутри коллбэка, вот так (используем стрелочную функцию, чтобы пробросить `this` и вызвать метод из `props`):

```
componentDidMount() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    // гарантированно получили объект с геопозицией
    const { coords: { latitude, longitude } } = position;

    // выводим результат в консоль  
    console.log('Coords after getCurrentPosition:', latitude, longitude);

    // дергаем экшн на сохранение координат
    this.props.weatherInfo(latitude, longitude);
  });
}
```

В качестве примера можно набросать простой код с сохранением координат в стейт (только пример не полностью рабочий из-за того, что `Geolocation` отключена на SO, но как рабочий код для [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MOZGoEZIK/19cjvmzp/2/) вполне подходит - только нужно разрешить отслеживать геолокацию в браузере):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      error: '',
      latitude: '',
      longitude: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        // гарантированно получили объект с геопозицией
        const { coords: { latitude, longitude } } = position;
        // выводим результат в консоль  
        console.log('Coords after getCurrentPosition:', latitude, longitude);
        // сохраним координаты в стейт
        this.setState({ latitude, longitude });
      },
      (error) => {
        // выводим результат в консоль  
        console.log('Error:', error);
        // сохраним текст ошибки для вывода в рендере
        this.setState({ error: error.message });
      }
    );
  }
    
  render() {
    const { latitude, longitude, error } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {!error &&
          <p>
            <span> Latitude: [{latitude}] </span>  
            <span> Longitude: [{longitude}] </span>
          </p>
        }
        {!!error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}
      </div> 
  )}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```